# Watch for Promise completion, then exec next Promise. Observable vs Promise?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, es6-promise

Basically I have calls to different SQL stored procedures that return Promises. Normally these would begin/end in random orders since they are asynchronous. I need to control the order each procedure is called.

I have tried using `.then()` on the callCustomerIUD promise, but `this._dataService.customerIUD(...).then(...)` doesn't run until after `callCustFieldIUD()`, so `customerFieldIUD` gets `this.key` as `undefined`.

```
saveChanges(record) {
   this.callCustomerIUD(record);
   this.callCustFieldIUD();
}

callCustomerIUD(record): Promise<any>{
   return this._dataService
        .customerIUD(...)
        .then(data => {
            //THIS KEY IS NEEDED FOR customerFieldIUD
            this.key = data[data.length-1].CustomerKey; 
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

callCustFieldIUD() : Promise<any>{
    //USES KEY FROM customerIUD
    this.fillCustomerField(this.key);
    return this._dataService.customerFieldIUD(...);
}
```

I have considered Observables, can I use them in this case? 
Here is my `data.service.ts` methods reference above. Should these be Observables and not Promises?

```
customerIUD(data: any) : Promise<any>{
    return this.fooHttp
        .postData(...);
}

customerFieldIUD(data: any) : Promise<any>{
    return this.fooHttp
        .postData(...);
}
```

Comment: Generally observables can do the job that ES6 promises do. I'm not sure what exactly happens in your methods but possibly RxJS operators could be helpful.

Comment: I'm new to observables. Do you think if I change the `Promise` types to `Observable` here I can use rxjs operators for the Observables?

Comment: It isn't clear if `fooHttp` is your own or third-party service. If it returns promises, they should be converted to observable with `fromPromise` operator, or the entire  `fooHttp` service should be modified to use observables.

Comment: It returns promises but I can't edit `fooHttp`. I will try `fromPromise`, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, observables would be great in this scenario

```
saveChanges(record) {
   this.callCustomerIUD(record).take(1).subscribe((data: any) => {
     // Observables can be subscribed to, like a .then() on a promise
     // data will be the response from the http call
     this.callCustFieldIUD(data).take(1).subscribe();
   });
}

callCustomerIUD(record): Observable<any>{
   return this._dataService.customerIUD(...)
}

callCustFieldIUD(data: any) : Observable<any>{
    //USES KEY FROM customerIUD
    this.fillCustomerField(this.key);
    return this._dataService.customerFieldIUD(...);
}
```

And in the service

```
customerIUD(data: any) : Observable<any>{
  return this.fooHttp.postData(...).map((res: any) => {
    return res.json();
  });
}

customerFieldIUD(data: any) : Observable<any>{
  return this.fooHttp.postData(...).map((res: any) => {
    return res.json();
  });
}
```

because the callCustFieldIUD() function is being called inside of the subscribe() to the observable returned by the callCustomerIUD() function, it won't execute until the data is there.

(This may not be the exact code you need. I'm not sure what has to happen when, but by subscribing to observables, you can be more strict about when functions get called)

Hope this helps

_______________ EDIT _________________________

I believe you can achieve this with promises too, just needs a slight refactor

```
saveChanges(record) {
   this.callCustomerIUD(record);
}

callCustomerIUD(record): Promise<any>{
   return this._dataService
        .customerIUD(...)
        .then(data => {
            // Instead of setting an instance var here, pass it in to the callCustFieldIUD() function
            this.callCustFieldIUD(data[data.length-1].CustomerKey);
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

callCustFieldIUD(customerKey: any) : Promise<any>{
    //USES KEY FROM customerIUD
    this.fillCustomerField(this.key);
    return this._dataService.customerFieldIUD(...);
}
```

Comment: @jhhoff02 I think there is a promise based solution as well. See my edit above

Comment: I used the Observables idea along with `fromPromise()` like estus suggested above

Answer (score 1):

The reason your first version does not work is because your program continues to go and do work while the http request is ongoing. A solution is to force the execution of callCustFieldIUD to occur after the key that it requires has been set. This same issue would arise and be resolved in a similar manner if you are using Observables.

You should be able to do:

```
saveChanges(record) {
    this.callCustomerIUD(record);
}

callCustomerIUD(record): Promise<any>{
return this._dataService
    .customerIUD(...)
    .then(data => {
        //THIS KEY IS NEEDED FOR customerFieldIUD
        this.key = data[data.length-1].CustomerKey;
        // Call the method you need to execute after the key is guaranteed
        // to be set
        this.callCustFieldIUD();
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```